# Laravel4 + Bootstrap: Icon + Warning message on the same line

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, alert, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this code for warning messaging on validation on a form:

```
@if($errors->any())
   <div class="alert alert-warning col-lg-12 centered">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i>

      <ul>
         {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) }}

      </ul>

   </div>
@endif
```

It appear the yellow box with the icon and the errors.
The little issue is that the icon is on one line, and the errors on another line.
How can i keep the icon on the left, at the same line of the errors?
Thank you

Comment: add `.alert i{float:left}` after Bootstrap's CSS?

Comment: Thank you man!
Can i ask you also how can i make it bigger?
i try with width: 24px; height: 24px;
But is not working

Comment: try something like: `.alert i {
    float: left;
    font-size: 64px;
    margin-right: 32px;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a float left to the glyphicon like:

```
.alert i { float: left; font-size: 64px; margin-right: 32px; margin-left:16px; }
```

Example: http://bootply.com/84046

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the icon inside  tag ;)

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong><i class="fa fa-warning"></i></strong> Your message here, <a href="#" class="alert-link" target="_blank">and your link here</a>!</div>]
```